# 'br' start tag on line #### position ## does not match end tag of 'font' epplus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am getting an error even when I dont update any anything.

when I run the code with epplus excel package  anyone have a solution , i am using an xlsm file.

```
    public void UpdateTheIntroExcelFile(IList<GeneralViewModel> Intro_Table, string Path)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Path != null)
            {
                ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.Commercial;
                var file = new FileInfo(fileName: Path);
                using var ExPackage = new ExcelPackage(file);
                var workSheet = ExPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[PositionID:0];
                //workSheet.Cells[3, 30].Value = "Success";
                ExPackage.Save();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: after extensive research i found that you can you can remove the br tag in the excel from the code. then save the file and the error does not come

Comment: How do you removed the br tag from the document?